# Настройка локали в Zend 3

Tags: php, zend-framework-3

Я получаю язык из get параметра в файле модуля

```
/**
 * @param ModuleManager $manager
 */
public function init(ModuleManager $manager): void
{
    $eventManager = $manager->getEventManager();
    $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEventManager->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', [$this, 'onDispatch'], 1);
}

/**
 * @param MvcEvent $event
 */
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $event): void
{
    $lang = $event->getTarget()->params()->fromQuery('lang');
    $event->getApplication()
        ->getServiceManager()
        ->setService(
            'translator',
            Translator::factory(['locale' => in_array($lang, self::$locales) ? $lang : 'en'])
        );
}
```

конфиг модуля:

```
'translator' => [
    'locale' => 'en',
    'translation_file_patterns' => [
        [
            'type'     => 'phpArray',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.php'
        ],
    ],
],
```

и язык всегда английский. если поменять locale на нужный язык - язык меняется, если поменять pattern на конкретный язык, например pl.php, язык меняется. Но без этого не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Translator как хелпер вызывается через Invokable factory ( см zend-18n\src\view\helperconfig.php) . я настраивал через делегаторы.  В config указываете

```
'Delegators'  => [
    \zend\i18n\translator\translator::class => [
        Translator\TranslatorDelegator::class
    ]
]
```

TranslatorDelegator - Ваш делегатор где меняете язык.